# How can I make this decorated Label control work?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I feel like this should have been a simple thing, but obviously I'm doing something dumb.

I am trying to make a `UserControl` with a `DependencyProperty` (an enum) that controls whether it simply displays the text supplied in its `Content` property verbatim, or appends it with some additional text.

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.UserControls.IndicatorLabel"
             x:Name="indicatorLabel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=EnumAssembly">
    <Label>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, ElementName=indicatorLabel}" />
            <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic"
                       Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IndicatorType}"
                                         Value="{x:Static enum:LabelIndicator.Optional}">
                                <Setter Property="Text"
                                        Value="(Optional)" />
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                        Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IndicatorType}"
                                         Value="{x:Static enum:LabelIndicator.Required}">
                                <Setter Property="Text"
                                        Value="(Required)" />
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                        Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Label>
</UserControl>
```

**UserControl's code-behind:**

```
public partial class IndicatorLabel : UserControl
    {
        public static DependencyProperty IndicatorTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IndicatorType", typeof(LabelIndicator), typeof(IndicatorLabel));
        public LabelIndicator IndicatorType
        {
            get => (LabelIndicator)GetValue(IndicatorTypeProperty);
            set => SetValue(IndicatorTypeProperty, value);
        }

        public IndicatorLabel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**Usage of the UserControl in another XAML page:**

```
<uc:IndicatorLabel Grid.Row="4"
                   Content="Description"
                   IndicatorType="Optional" />
```

I expected to see:  Description *(Optional)*

In fact, I haven't been able to get what's in the UserControl's XAML to have any affect at all, so long as the `Content` property is set.

**EDIT:**

The reason I say it has no effect is because even if put a literal string in the `Text` property of the first `TextBlock`, whatever is in the `Content` property still displays.  It seems as if neither `TextBlock` is truly showing.

So why is this happening?  Is it not possible to use the `Content` property as a way to get text into the parts that I really mean to display?  Am I breaking some WPF rule about `Content` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off; yes you don't want to use `Content`. What your XAML for your UC *really* says is:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Content>
        ... All that stuff
    </UserControl.Content>
</UserControl>
```

So when you assign Content in the parent XAML you are just overwriting all that. Use a different property (like "Text") instead. If instead of `UserControl` you did an actual `Control` (with separate `ControlTemplate` and everything) then you could use that name

Also, the `{Binding IndicatorType}` is looking at the inherited data context. You should either set the User Control's data context to itself or use `x:Reference` to tell it to look at the user control itself.

Comment: I'll do that.  Check the edit for something you made me realize that I forgot to mention.

Comment: @DonBoitnott understood now; yeah you don't want to be using content. See my edit.

Comment: So it's basically what I suspected it to be.  I guess I was hoping for an a-ha from someone to demonstrate a passable work-around.  Just seems like the instinctual use would be the one that fails:  set Content.  Instead, you have to know about a separate `Text` property, that no one would expect a `UserControl` to have.  Maybe I'm overthinking it, but it seems to force you to do non-intuitive things to make it work.

Comment: @DonBoitnott For text I would think a "Text" property makes *more* sense; I always felt the button's "Content" one was confusing (though I know why it is that way"